# Google Books Api Searching by ISBN doesn't always work

Tags: json, google-books, google-books-api

I'm not always getting results when searching by isbn with the Google Books API

For example, this ISBN won't work with the ISBN query

```
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:9780593437810&maxResults=40&langRestrict=en
```

but if I remove it like so:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=9780593437810&maxResults=40&langRestrict=en
```

then it brings up a bunch of results but I'm trying to narrow it down to only one. The isbn query works on some books and not others